# Escape from LeChuck's fortress without using grog?

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge

Yesterday we were revisiting *Monkey Island 2: LeChuck's Revenge* (the easy mode) and one of us got to LeChuck's fortress without having grog in the inventory.

As you normally need some to put out the candle and escape, is this game effectively lost? Is there another way to proceed from there?

Unfortunately we don't have any saved states from before hanging above the acid pit.

Comment: I have to ask- how did you accomplish that?

Comment: @Studoku-ReinstateMonica In the easy mode you don't need the grog for anything before that situation. So it's actually quite easy to accomplish that :]

Answer (score 2):

I have to start the answer with a facepalm.

It appears that in the easy mode you can just talk to Wally, and he will somehow get you down there.

How could we not try this!

For reference:

- https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/562680-monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge/faqs/6447